# Div Tags are showing vertically instead of Horizontally?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 div elements each with width of 4 i want to align them all of 4 in a row i am also using a toggle button to show these div because by default these div display are none but when i user click the toggle button div will show to him the problem is that div are showing but they are vertically showing in three rows i want to show them horizontally in a single row.

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="custom-control custom-switch" style="margin-left:25px">
   @Html.CheckBox("Select Raw Targets", new { @class = "custom-control-input", id = "rawTargetSelection" })
   <label class="custom-control-label" for="rawTargetSelection">Select Raw Targets</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
<!-- Raw Target Tags Values Tabs Starts Here -->
                            <div class="row" id="Real_Tag_Targets" style="display:none">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Select Real Tag Targets</label>
                                        @Html.DropDownList("Raw Tag Targets", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.rawTagTargetValue, new { @class = "form-control add_item", @multiple = true, id = "Raw_Tag_Target_List" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Select Real Tag Min Targets</label>
                                        @Html.DropDownList("Raw Tag Min Targets", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.rawTagTargetMin, new { @class = "form-control add_item", @multiple = true, id = "Raw_Tag_Min_Target_List" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Select Real Tag Max Targets</label>
                                        @Html.DropDownList("Raw Tag Max Targets", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.rawTagTargetMax, new { @class = "form-control add_item", @multiple = true, id = "Raw_Tag_Max_Target_List" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

 $("#rawTargetSelection").change(function () {
             var x = document.getElementById("Real_Tag_Targets");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
              x.style.display = "block";
            }
            else
            {
               x.style.display = "none";
            }
        });
```

[image]

Comment: which browser do you test?

Comment: @CemFirat Google Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting a row after a col, without the complete code its hard to tell. Better example code recommended. Also try it without the server code, and just the html output since this is obviously a markup-problem. 
You can tell from the example below, the markup col-md-4 works as expected (if screensize allows it).

Also: you're setting the row (which uses display:flex)  to display:block;

```js
$("#rawTargetSelection").change(function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Real_Tag_Targets");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    //x.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="custom-control custom-switch" style="margin-left:25px">

    <label class="custom-control-label" for="rawTargetSelection">Select Raw Targets</label>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Raw Target Tags Values Tabs Starts Here -->
<div class="row" id="Real_Tag_Targets">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Select Real Tag Targets</label> -input-
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Select Real Tag Min Targets</label> -input-
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Select Real Tag Min Targets</label> -input-
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Raw Target Tags Values Tabs Starts Here -->
<div class="row" id="Real_Tag_Targets">
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Select Real Tag Targets</label> -input-
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Select Real Tag Min Targets</label> -input-
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Select Real Tag Min Targets</label> -input-
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  div, label {
    border: 1px dotted #f00;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: basically when i removed style="display:none" then its working fine but when i add this to hide this div on page loading and then press toggle then these div are vertically aligned.

Comment: if you're setting the css look at the default setting and set it back to this. 
bootstrap row uses flex , added it to the answer:
display: flex;

Comment: no i am not using css i a just setting the style:none to style:block using JS

Comment: x.style.display = "block";  is setting the css.. you should change it to x.style.display = "flex";

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
x.style.display = "inline";
```

in your function

Comment: should use flex

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be with your @html checkbox style property, please check that. because without that it works.

Comment: its also working when i remove style:none from div element